# Is there a great cheap or free site for the CISSP exam?

Tags: cissp

CCCure is not free and many others that are recommended on the site are not free....any suggestions?

Comment: I like these youtube videos. This company puts on free training every once in aw hile this is from last year i believe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzUPXEQ-adA

Answer (score 2):

Check out Eric Conrad's 500 questions and podcasts.  Thanks to Eric and to Syngress/Elsevier for making these available!  http://www.ericconrad.com/2014/04/my-500-cissp-questions.html

My experience with practice questions is that they're really going to exercise what you learned from a particular book; in this case, the free questions test you on information you can get from CISSP Study Guide. It was my primary reference for the exam.  Caveat: if you're not using that book as a reference then the questions may scare you, but ... they're free, and they're great.